# manage.py runserver in virtualenv using wrong django version

Tags: python, django, virtualenv

I created a virtualenv and installed Django 1.5 in it

```
(virtpy33) c:\django_projects>python
Python 3.3.2 (v3.3.2:d047928ae3f6, May 16 2013, 00:03:43) [MSC v.1600 32 bit (Intel)] on      win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import django
>>> django.VERSION
(1, 5, 1, 'final', 0)
>>> ^Z
```

then I created a project and ran manage.py runserver, but it says it's running version 1.4

```
(virtpy33) c:\django_projects>django-admin.py startproject virtres
(virtpy33) c:\django_projects>cd virtres
(virtpy33) c:\django_projects\virtres>manage.py runserver
Validating models...
0 errors found
Django version 1.4, using settings 'virtres.settings'
Development server is running at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
```

I'm new to virtualenv and Django. Is there anything else I need to do? Like edit the settings.py file or manage.py file or something?

I have Django 1.4 on my system (Windows Vista) under my Python27 directory (not in a virtual environment), but I set up a virtualenv so I could use Django 1.5 and Python 3.

Please help!

Comment: I know this seems silly, but what happens if you run `python manage.py runserver`? Do you end up with the right version?

Comment: How did you create your virtualenv? Did you try it the `--no-site-packages` option?

Comment: python manage.py runserver did the trick. thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you run `manage.py` on its own, Windows is pulling it off of the main Windows `PATH`, and then running it off of the main Windows association with Python, which is your default installed version of Python, and thus outside your virtualenv.

Inside your virtualenv, try running `python manage.py runserver` and see what happens.

Comment: Ran into this post and in fact the suggestion made it work for me too.I'll never get to understand Windows shell logic.

Comment: This isn't limited to just windows. Running manage.py on my linux instance had the same issue.